# Pulp: variable to measure extent infeasible in supply problem

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

I am currently modelling a supply problem that attempts to optimise a rail schedule which moves products from a production plant, to a warehouse to satisfy sales.

The model is working fine (thanks in part to SO!) however I would like to create a variable that shows the extent of a supply shortfall. Currently if the current inventory is 0, and demand is > 0, then the model is unable to satisfy the constraints and returns 'unfeasible'.

I would like to define a variable to captures the shortfall so that the end result is always 'optimal' even though a shortfall is realised, and shows this extent.

i.e.

```
desired_output_df.head(10)

>>>

date            product      current_inventory     sales_demand     inventory_shortfall
'2020-01-01'    'AFM'        10000                 5000             0
'2020-01-02'    'AFM'        5000                  5000             0
'2020-01-03'    'AFM'        0                     6000             6000
```

Unfortunately the amount of code is too extensive to create an MRE, so i am hoping that a steer is possible given the above and below code:

```
# Objective Function
model += pulp.lpSum([
    storage_inventory_target_overage[(date, product)]
    + storage_inventory_target_shortage[(date, product)]
    + storage_inventory_shortage[(date, product)] 
    for date, product in storage_inventory_vars]
), 'Minimise stockpile target shortfalls and excesses'

# Storage plant stockpile target, max/min and shortage constraints
for date, product in storage_inventory_vars:
  max_level = storage_stockpile_max[grade]
  min_level = 0
  target_level = storage_stockpile_target[product]
  model += storage_inventory_vars[(date, product)] <= max_level

  # Storage Inventory Target Constraints
  model += storage_inventory_target_overage[(date, product)] >= 0
  model += storage_inventory_target_overage[(date, product)] - binary[(date, product)] * 100000000 <= 0
  model += storage_inventory_target_shortage[(date, product)] >= 0
  model += storage_inventory_target_shortage[(date, product)] - (1 - binary[(date, product)]) * 10000000 <= 0
  model += storage_inventory_vars[(date, product)] >= target_level \
    + storage_inventory_target_overage[(date, product)] \
    - storage_inventory_target_shortage[(date, product)] 

  # storage Inventory Shortages
  model += storage_stockpile_shortage[(date, product)] >= 0
  model += storage_inventory_vars[(date, product)] <= 0 == storage_stockpile_shortage[(date, product)]  

# Sales Demand
# storage stockpile levels must meet sales demand
for date, product in storage_inventory_vars:
  pulp.lpSum(storage_inventory_vars[date, product]) >= sales_demand[date][product]
```

The variables `storage_stockpile_shortage[(date, product)]`, `storage_inventory_target_shortage` and 
`storage_inventory_target_overage` are the variables I would like to measure.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure this  ` <= 0 == ` works as you expect? I would place brackets anyway.  Try to `print(model)`, it may help to find the wrong part of the formulation.

Comment: @AskoldIlvento - The intention of this line is to set the constraint that the shortage must be a positive number, and then to state that the shortage is equal to the difference from when the current inventory, storage_inventory_vars[(date, product)] is less than zero i.e. negative inventory. I am not sure if this is the correct way however.

Comment: Big M's should never just be 100000000. You should think hard about a good, tight value for each big-M you need. Any value above say 1e5 is dangerous (but I have seen cases where things go wrong even earlier).

Comment: Thanks Erwin - noted. I receive an error using this current logic so clearly something is not quite correct - is it possible this is something to do with it?

Comment: If "an error" means infeasible then the answer is "could be".

Comment: Also I never add things like shortage and overage everywhere: measure them in one place.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Unfortunately not an 'infeasible', more a 'SolverError'.  When you say measure in one place, do you mean using a variable that measures both overage/shortfall?

Comment: I don't know what SolverError precisely means. Inspect the solver log. You can have both overage and shortage, but measure them only once. E.g. `inventory = target_inventory - shortage + overage` and from there on only use `inventory`.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thank you for the advice - would you know how to structure this as a solution please?

Comment: I would suggest to first write down the mathematical model (on a piece of paper). Once you have that, transcribing this into Python/Pulp code is much easier.

Comment: Alas, sadly this is documented/designed quite heavily but the documentation and any examples of how to do this in python is quite scarce, hence I have had to ask SO how to model this.